# How can I make a remote logon Powershell script run as the locally logged on user?

Tags: windows, powershell, psexec

I'm trying to use the Microsoft User State Migration tool with Powershell; the way the program "loadstate.exe" works is that it needs to be called locally so that it will load up a remotely saved state of the user's profile and then restore it to the local computer.

I am seeking to automate this with Powershell; in order to do this, I have written a script that will elevate the user to run Powershell in Executive/Administrative mode and then execute the following command, against the USMT program that is installed on all of our computers:

```
c:\usmt\loadstate.exe /i:$configfile $storepath
```

Where $configfile is the name of the configuration file and the store path is the name of where the files are stored at. This all works, except that when run from remote, it seems to try to execute it from the System context - the desktop files are instead restored with the ACL permissions of  CREATOR OWNER, SYSTEM, and Administrators - rather than giving it to the actually logged on user.

So if I have it set as a logon script, and try to have it execute when the user GuineaPig logs in, it will seek to restore the files and it will actually restore it - but all desktop items will be invisible to GuineaPig because she doesn't have any rights to see them.

If I just have the script locally, say on the user's C:\ DRIVE, and then right-click and "Run as Powershell Script", it works fine.

How do I execute this remote powershell script(located on our domain controller) so that it will actually run it in the context of the local user?

Alternately, how do I just tell the Group Policy of a logon script to just run something from the user's computer? I can also just set the script to be copied to the C:\ of every local computer, I just need the logon policy to actually run it from the C:\ of every local computer as the locally logged on user.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using Group Policy, and making it part of the User (not Machine) policy?

Comment: Because this is from a virtual computer, it needs to run as part of a Group Loopback policy but the logon script itself is executed from User Configuration. If I put it into the script directly to run "C:\usmt\" etc, it tries to run it from the server's C:\usmt because the script is on the server, etc, not from the local computer's.

Comment: If you run it as Machine policy it's going to run under the local system account.

Comment: Is there a way that I can force otherwise, though? Can I write the powershell script to use an Invoke-Command to run a local script on the computer itself?

Comment: Use Powershell.exe -File, and source the file from the server.

Comment: Ultimately, I solved the issue by having the script itself composed to be automatically replicated to the D:/ of each computer and then setting a GPO to run it through task scheduler one minute after the user's logon. This results in the script running with the correct user/environmental details such that it actually works correctly.